# React-Redux: Dispatching on Constructor -> props.store.state not updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I am very new at React and Redux both, I have only been using both for about 2 - 3 weeks to develop an alpha version of an application.

Though most of the tutorials on using Redux with React seemed to be pretty complicated I found one that allowed me to get some quick code down to try very simple scenarios within my application.

The main problem I seem to face at the moment is: I want to click on an image of and show the details of said property on another page (routed to using react-router, passing id in the path - to clarify in the current code i am using the hardcoded id of 22 an the id is not passed in the path yet). I thought it would as straight forward as clicking on the app then in either the constructor or componentWillMount method I could call this.props.foo(id) and then get the property using this.props.store.foo but it seems as though the store is not updated at that time. But if i called this.props.foo(id) in the handleClick method of the page before redirecting then it would work, but on refresh the store is back to default and causes an error.

I am just wondering if I am just taking a completely wrong approach to this.. or just missing something.

The code may be too much, just let me know if I should trim it down...
Functions to look for are the:

handleImageClick() - > Results.js

constructor() - > BuyDetails.js
Code:

Index.js

```
let state = {
    results: [],
    selectedState:{},
};

let reducer = (state, action) => {
  console.log("in reducer" + action.type);
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_RESULTS': 
        console.log("in reducer add");
        console.log("in reducer results = " + action.results);
        var newState = Object.assign({}, state)
        newState.results = action.results
        console.log("in reducer add " + JSON.stringify(newState))
        return newState
    case 'GET_RESULTS': 
        console.log("in reducer get state = " + state.results[0].id);
        var newState = Object.assign({}, state)
        for (var result of state.results){
            if (result.id === action.id){
                console.log(result.img)

                newState.selectedState = result
                console.log(newState.selectedState.location.address)

            }
        }
        console.log(newState.selectedState.location.address)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(newState));
        return newState
    default: 
        return state
  }
}

let store = createStore(reducer, state)

let mapStateToProps = state => ({
  store: state
})

let mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  addResults: (results) => dispatch({type: 'ADD_RESULTS', results:results}),
  getSelectedResult: (id) => dispatch({type: 'GET_RESULTS', id:id}),
})

const ConnectedAppComponent = connect(
    mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps
)(App)

const ConnectedResultsComponent = connect(
    mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps
)(Results)

const ConnectedBuyDetailsComponent = connect(
    mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps
)(BuyDetails)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={ConnectedAppComponent}/>
        {/* add the routes here */}
        <Route path="/results" component={ConnectedResultsComponent}/>
        <Route path="/buyDetails" component={ConnectedBuyDetailsComponent}/>
      </Router>
  </Provider>, 
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Results.js

```
class Results extends Component{
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {open: true, openProfile:false, anchorEl: null,dataSet:this.props.store.results};
      console.log(this.state.dataSet.length)
      console.log(this.state.dataSet[0].img)

   }
   handleTouchTap = (event) => {
    // This prevents ghost click.
    console.log("touch tap");
    event.preventDefault();
    const tempState = this.state;
    tempState.openProfile = true
    tempState.anchorEl = event.currentTarget
    this.setState(tempState)
    /*this.setState({
      openProfile: true,
      anchorEl: event.currentTarget,
    });*/
  };

  handleRequestClose = () => {
    const tempState = this.state;
    tempState.openProfile = false
    tempState.anchorEl = null
    this.setState(tempState)
   /*this.setState({
      openProfile: false,
    });*/
  };
  handleToggle = () => this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
  handleImageClick(){
      //This is where i could be doing this.props.getSelectedResult(22); and it would work but causes issues on refresh
      const path = `/buyDetails`
      this.context.router.push(path)
  }
  render() {
    return <MuiThemeProvider>
          <div className="Results" id="Results" style={styles}>
          <div>
            <Toolbar style={appBarStyle}>

              <IconButton iconClassName="material-icons"
                style={{bottom: '0',height:'auto'}}
                onClick={this.handleToggle}>
                menu
                {/*<FontIcon className="material-icons" color={grey900} onClick={this.handleToggle}>menu</FontIcon>*/}
              </IconButton>              
              <ToolbarGroup style={groupStyle}>
                <ToolbarSeparator style={seperatorMargin}/>
                 <FontIcon style={searchIconnStyle} className="material-icons">search</FontIcon>
                 <ToolBarSearchField />
              </ToolbarGroup>

              <ToolbarGroup>
                <ToolbarSeparator style={residentialSeperatorStyle}/>
                <FlatButton label="Residential" style={selectedToolBarButtonStyle}/>
                <ToolbarSeparator style={seperatorStyle}/>
                <FlatButton label="Commerical" style={toolBarButtonStyle}/>
                <ToolbarSeparator style={seperatorStyle}/>
                <FlatButton label="JoellyR" style={toolBarButtonStyle} onTouchTap={this.handleTouchTap}/>
                <Popover open={this.state.openProfile}
                  anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl}
                  anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'bottom'}}
                  targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
                  onRequestClose={this.handleRequestClose}>
                  <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Price Range" />
                  <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="values" />
                </Popover>
              </ToolbarGroup>

            </Toolbar>
            <ToolBarFilterFields fieldNames={['Buy', 'Sell', 'Rent', 'Businesses', 'Mortgages']} displaySeperator={false}/>
            </div>
            <Drawer
              open={this.state.open}
              containerStyle={{top:'inherit', boxShadow:'(0,0,0,0)', border:'0px', borderRight:'1px solid', borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)'}}>
            </Drawer>
            <div style={this.state.open ? drawerExpanded : drawerCollapsed }>
              <Paper style={paperStyle}>
                <ToolBarFilterFields fieldNames={['Filters', 'Price', 'Bath', 'Beds', 'Type', 'Style']} displaySeperator={true}/>
                <ResultGridList dataSet={this.state.dataSet} onClick = {() => this.handleImageClick()}/>
              </Paper>
            </div>
          </div>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
  }
}
Results.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object
}

export default Results;
```

BuyDetails.js

```
class BuyDetails extends Component{
   constructor(props) {
      super(props); 


       //dispatching the action here
    this.props.getSelectedResult(22);

    //getting the selected object from the props.state ... but it will still be = {}
    this.state = {open: true, openProfile:false, anchorEl: null,data:this.props.store.selectedState};
   }
   componentWillMount() {



  }

   handleTouchTap = (event) => {
    console.log('in buy detail: ' + JSON.stringify(this.props.store.selectedState) + JSON.stringify(this.props.store.results));
    // This prevents ghost click.
    console.log("touch tap2");
    event.preventDefault();
    const tempState = this.state;
    tempState.openProfile = true
    tempState.anchorEl = event.currentTarget
    this.setState(tempState)
    /*this.setState({
      openProfile: true,
      anchorEl: event.currentTarget,
    });*/
  };

  handleRequestClose = () => {
    const tempState = this.state;
    tempState.openProfile = false
    tempState.anchorEl = null
    this.setState(tempState)
   /*this.setState({
      openProfile: false,
    });*/
  };
   handleToggle = () => this.setState({open: !this.state.open});

  render() {
    return <MuiThemeProvider>
          <div className="BuyDetails" id="BuyDetails" style={styles}>
          <div>
            <Toolbar style={appBarStyle}>

              <IconButton iconClassName="material-icons"
                style={{bottom: '0',height:'auto'}}
                onClick={this.handleToggle}>
                menu
                {/*<FontIcon className="material-icons" color={grey900} onClick={this.handleToggle}>menu</FontIcon>*/}
              </IconButton>              
              <ToolbarGroup style={groupStyle}>
                <ToolbarSeparator style={seperatorMargin}/>
                 <FontIcon style={searchIconnStyle} className="material-icons">search</FontIcon>
                 <ToolBarSearchField />
              </ToolbarGroup>

              <ToolbarGroup>
                <ToolbarSeparator style={residentialSeperatorStyle}/>
                <FlatButton label="Residential" style={selectedToolBarButtonStyle}/>
                <ToolbarSeparator style={seperatorStyle}/>
                <FlatButton label="Commerical" style={toolBarButtonStyle}/>
                <ToolbarSeparator style={seperatorStyle}/>
                <FlatButton label="JoellyR" style={toolBarButtonStyle} onTouchTap={this.handleTouchTap}/>
                <Popover open={this.state.openProfile}
                  anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl}
                  anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'bottom'}}
                  targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
                  onRequestClose={this.handleRequestClose}>
                  <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Price Range" />
                  <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="values" />
                </Popover>
              </ToolbarGroup>

            </Toolbar>
            </div>
            <Drawer
              open={this.state.open}
              containerStyle={{top:'inherit', boxShadow:'(0,0,0,0)', border:'0px', borderRight:'1px solid', borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)'}}>
            </Drawer>
            <div style={this.state.open ? drawerExpanded : drawerCollapsed }>
              <Paper style={paperStyle}>
                <BuyDetailGridList data={this.props.store.selectedState}/>
              </Paper>
            </div>
          </div>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
  }
}
function isEmpty(obj) {
    for(var key in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
export default BuyDetails;
```

Thanks Everyone... In Advance :)

**+++UPDATE - Still not working+++**

Here is the code for another approach i tried which was just calling the dispatch in componentWillMount() then just passing this.props.store.selectedState directly to the child component.

BuyDetails.js

```
class BuyDetails extends Component{
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {open: true, openProfile:false, anchorEl: null,data:{}};
      //console.log('in buy details '+ JSON.stringify(this.state.data));

   }
   componentWillMount() {

    //dispatching the action here... it is still this.props.store.selectedState is still = {}
    this.props.getSelectedResult(22);
  }

   handleTouchTap = (event) => {
    console.log('in buy detail: ' + JSON.stringify(this.props.store.selectedState) + JSON.stringify(this.props.store.results));
    // This prevents ghost click.
    console.log("touch tap2");
    event.preventDefault();
    const tempState = this.state;
    tempState.openProfile = true
    tempState.anchorEl = event.currentTarget
    this.setState(tempState)
    /*this.setState({
      openProfile: true,
      anchorEl: event.currentTarget,
    });*/
  };

  handleRequestClose = () => {
    const tempState = this.state;
    tempState.openProfile = false
    tempState.anchorEl = null
    this.setState(tempState)
   /*this.setState({
      openProfile: false,
    });*/
  };
   handleToggle = () => this.setState({open: !this.state.open});

  render() {
    return <MuiThemeProvider>
          <div className="BuyDetails" id="BuyDetails" style={styles}>
          <div>
            <Toolbar style={appBarStyle}>

              <IconButton iconClassName="material-icons"
                style={{bottom: '0',height:'auto'}}
                onClick={this.handleToggle}>
                menu
                {/*<FontIcon className="material-icons" color={grey900} onClick={this.handleToggle}>menu</FontIcon>*/}
              </IconButton>              
              <ToolbarGroup style={groupStyle}>
                <ToolbarSeparator style={seperatorMargin}/>
                 <FontIcon style={searchIconnStyle} className="material-icons">search</FontIcon>
                 <ToolBarSearchField />
              </ToolbarGroup>

              <ToolbarGroup>
                <ToolbarSeparator style={residentialSeperatorStyle}/>
                <FlatButton label="Residential" style={selectedToolBarButtonStyle}/>
                <ToolbarSeparator style={seperatorStyle}/>
                <FlatButton label="Commerical" style={toolBarButtonStyle}/>
                <ToolbarSeparator style={seperatorStyle}/>
                <FlatButton label="JoellyR" style={toolBarButtonStyle} onTouchTap={this.handleTouchTap}/>
                <Popover open={this.state.openProfile}
                  anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl}
                  anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'bottom'}}
                  targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
                  onRequestClose={this.handleRequestClose}>
                  <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Price Range" />
                  <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="values" />
                </Popover>
              </ToolbarGroup>

            </Toolbar>
            </div>
            <Drawer
              open={this.state.open}
              containerStyle={{top:'inherit', boxShadow:'(0,0,0,0)', border:'0px', borderRight:'1px solid', borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)'}}>
            </Drawer>
            <div style={this.state.open ? drawerExpanded : drawerCollapsed }>
              <Paper style={paperStyle}>
                <BuyDetailGridList data={this.props.store.selectedState}/>
              </Paper>
            </div>
          </div>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
  }
}
function isEmpty(obj) {
    for(var key in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
export default BuyDetails;
```

Comment: you say you're passing the id in the path but you don't have any routes that are handling a path with an id in it. it would look like `<Route path="/:itemId/details" ... />`

Comment: Sorry i should have been more clear.. I want to pass the id in the path but at the moment i am just trying to pass in the id as a hardcoded value... 22

Comment: it is also recommended to avoid using `this.setState` referencing `this.state` (as in `this.setState({open: !this.state.open});`) as state operations are typically batched to improve performance. The proper way is to use `this.setState((prevState, props) => { return someNewState; })`

Comment: Oh thanks for the tip! Some of the code is bits and pieces i tried to follow here and there... I may need to go back and do some refactoring.. Thanks tho! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't fetch the item in the details component, at least not explicitly.

Consider:

A details component:

```
class DetailsComponent extends React.Component {
    // the item is now available in props.item
}

function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
    return {
        item: state.getSelectedItem()
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DetailsComponent);
```

A list component:

```
class ListComponent extends React.Component {
    ...

    onImageClick = (item) => {
        this.props.setSelectedItem(item);
    }

    ...
}
```

This relies on `set`/`getSelectedItem` actions which set some relevant state. The details component will automatically grab the selected item when it's mounted.

Another thing to consider would be, if the two components were being rendered simultaneously (in a list/detail style UI, for example), would be to lift the selected state up into the parent state (parent of *both* components).

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    ...

    onItemSelected = (item) => {
        this.setState({ selectedItem: item });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ListComponent onItemSelected={ this.onItemSelected }/>
            <DetailsComponent item={ this.state.selectedItem }/>
        );
    }
}
```

That all said, you posted a lot of code and it's a little hard to tell what's going on. Hopefully something I've written above helps with your issue.

Comment: Hi Tyler, thanks for the speedy reply :).. Though i have tried this approach and it does work (you are correct) the problem I faced with this issue is that .. On page reload the state is gone... Though your reply does get me thinking that the issue may lie somewhere else.. maybe persistence is needed for the redux store? But I am trying to avoid that...maybe add the call to the server into the GET_RESULTS reducer method? not to sure

Comment: "maybe add the call to the server into the GET_RESULTS reducer method" --

i don't think it's good practice to use action creators within reducers. Update the state when the root component is remounted or use React Router's onWorkspaceEnter to check to see if the necessary information is available in the store and, if not, sync.

Comment: another option is to use a module like https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist... although it isn't necessary.

Comment: Yea I am trying to avoid persistence... so i will take a look at onWorkspace enter.. TYVM :)